# How can I stop the Windows Store and Photo application repeatedly opening on their own?

Tags: windows-10

How can you stop Windows Store and Photo application repeatedly opening on their own?

If I <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I can see the two applications. Even if I close them, they reopen after a period

Yet they don't appear if I <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

*UPDATE: it's stopped happening ... there have been various Windows Updates, maybe one of them?*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a program, I would suggest uninstalling it.

If you don't see it in the "programs and features" menu in the Control Panel, I would suggest disabling the service.

Go to Control Panel -> Administrative tools -> Services and look for services pertaining to the specifies programs. Select Disable on start up and click "stop" then hit apply.

Comment: In this case, I do want to have the applications installed, just not keep appearing in and tab

Comment: Alright then, in that case, perhaps you should go find it in the CONTROL PANEL -> ADMINISTRATIVE TOOLS -> SERVICES right click the program, select properties, in the drop down for "Startup type" select Manual, then click "stop" then click apply

Comment: This is specific to one of my PC's ... on the other two, I'm not getting this reopening, just my Alienware laptop. These are both Metro (or whatever the proper name is), and on other machines, after closing they remain closed. I'm just stumped as to what can be reopening them after a short period

Comment: That's definitely an odd scenario. I'm honestly not sure what could be causing it but disabling the services would for sure stop it from occuring. Maybe someone else who has run into this issue will have a better answer for you.